# Syntax of Jacobi elliptic functions

Tags: integration, jacobian, elliptic-functions

I'm trying to understand this paper on blackholes
https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1979A%26A....75..228L

the following is in the paper:
[picture of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmpIM.png)
However, I do not understand the syntax of the Jacobi elliptic function in (13).
Do they not take 2 parameters, usually (u,m)
Why is there only one parameter here, and why is it in curly brackets?
Part of the parameter is an Elliptic integral of modulus k, would it be safe to assume the modulus of the Jacobi elliptic function is also k?

[Edit]

To clarify, the equation in the above image can be simplified for this posting to be:

$$1/r = g*(sn(a*γ + F(ζ, k))^2$$

My confusion is that from everything I've read about the Jacobi elliptic function sn, it takes 2 parameters, usually (u,m) but in this paper, they only have 1 parameter $(a*γ + F(ζ, k))$, in curly brackets (Which I couldn't get to show in the equation above so I'm using regular brackets). Is it fair to assume the author used k, from F(ζ, k), as the modulus for sn as well? Or is this some well-known syntax?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I presume the second argument might be suppressed when it's fixed and supposed to be understood from the context. (At least for Jacobi theta functions that's quite common.) In that case it should hopefully be explained elsewhere in the paper, eg soon after the introduction or in an appendix.